# What is the quickest way to check whether I already have a given package?

Tags: packages, file-lookup

What is the quickest way to check (on Linux) whether I already have a given package?  In particular I'm interested in whether there is something that will take less time than the 20 seconds or so it would take me to create a tiny latex document and try to compile it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
kpsewhich pkgname.sty
kpsewhich clsname.cls
```

Comment: And this not only tells you if you have the package, but also the path where it's installed.

Answer (score 13):

The standard tool works not only on Linux but also on Windows systems: at the command prompt, the command

```
kpsewhich name.sty
```

prints path and file name of one file `name.sty` if it can be found, otherwise nothing.

```
kpsewhich -all name.sty
```

prints all occurences if there are several (try `kpsewhich -all texmf.cnf`).

It uses ls-R files but could search the disk as well if you specify the option -must-exist. kpsewhich recognizes a lot of format names. Beside tex formats like .cls, .sty, .tex it finds font files, bib files and many more.

Type

```
kpsewhich --help
```

or

```
man kpsewhich
```

to learn more or have a look at this [kpsewhich manpage](http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/kpsewhich/).

This standalone program belongs to the kpathsea library. To read about it, type

```
texdoc kpathsea
```

at the command prompt. As you may know, texdoc is another very useful command for the shell.

Comment: Although the additional information in your answer is useful, I've accepted Geoffrey's because he was first, and besides, you don't need the extra rep.

Comment: @Mark: don't worry, it's fine :) I was just typing and thought I'll send as well.

Comment: @Mark, @Stefan: yay! rep! :))