# What is the command prompt ? How can I use it in Texmaker for package installation using "kpsewhich" tool

Tags: texmaker

Someone is [answering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144683/how-to-install-automatically-a-new-document-class-in-texmaker-through-miktex/144865?noredirect=1#144865) me to use a command (`kpsewhich --help`) in the command prompt. I have a stupid question: what is the "command prompt" and how can I use it in `Texmaker`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt if you use Windows. If you use Linux, we call it *Terminal* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator

Comment: Ah, on Windows, press the Windows key (that one with the logo) + R to open the Run box. Then type `cmd` and hit `enter`.

Comment: Open TeXmaker-->Go to `Tools` menu--> `Open Terminal` (3rd from bottom) on [Latest version: Texmaker 4.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)

Comment: In an effort to make the Q clear, I have made an edit , hope this is what you are looking for ? include any more details to give clarity.

Comment: Close Voters: The OP seems to be new, Please give him some time until the Q crosses the front roll, don't close immediately within 1 hr and in a hurry. The Q seems to be on on-topic (LaTeX Editor) and related command line approaches are very important and life saving for verifying installation/packages.

Comment: @texenthusiast: Yes exactly. Thanks for the editing. Your comment about the path was useful, I think should be updated to a response.  
I previously stated that is not good that regular users are maintaining this information asymmetry with regard to new users. I think this initial gap should be reduce not increase. Of course is easier to put a question "on hold" but is not a win-win situation to none of users. I'm not saying: "don't put my question "on hold"", I'm just asking you put in the place "I'm a new user" is it useful or not?

Comment: @Emanuel I have made some answer based on sigur's comments and mine, you can add or suggest any additions incase you could not follow. Thanks

Comment: @texenthusiast: [tlmgr](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) was really useful. I think Sigur's comments are also useful to other users. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Sigur pointed out :

**On Windows (Command Prompt)**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt

**Opening Command Prompt on Windows**: press the `Windows` key (that one with the logo) + `R` to open the Run box. Then type `cmd` and hit enter or

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window

**On Linux (Terminal)**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

**Open Terminal In Texmaker**:

Open TeXmaker-->Go to `Tools` menu--> `Open Terminal` (3rd from bottom) on [Latest version: Texmaker 4.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html).

> Addendum for quick and powerful command line tools:

**Verify a latex installation**: Commandline/Terminal:

To verify/test a latex installation(TeXlive or MiKTeX) using commandline/terminal, one can use

`latex small2e` to get the `small2e.dvi` (or)

`latex sample2e` to get the `sample2e.dvi`

`pdflatex small2e` to get the `small2e.pdf` (or)

`pdflatex sample2e` to get the `sample2e.pdf`

`pdflatex sample2e` to get the `sample2e.pdf`

`xetex opentype-info` to get the `opentype-info.pdf`

**Verify or install/detect an installation of class package**
using `kpsewhich --help` standalone path lookup tool

`kpsewhich pkgname.sty` and `kpsewhich clsname.cls`

Related Q & A : [What is the quickest way to check whether I already have a given package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1830/15717)

Some command line tools on [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) distribution that work crossplatform(Windows/Linux/Mac)

**[tlmgr](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html)**: TeX Live package manager

- `tlmgr update --self --all` helps to keep updated distro with latest packages 
  and bug fixes
- `tlmgr info pkg-name` to know the version/revision of package and details etc
- `tlmgr install pkg-name` to install a package
- [tlmgr Examples](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#EXAMPLES)

**[texdoc/texdoctk](http://tug.org/texdoc/)** : The powerfull documentation tool

Related Q [Which books can I read via texdoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27636/15717)

Remember commandline tools (CUI) instead of GUI's are more popular on Linux/Mac which really are life savers for debugging/scripting and much more. Even on windows it serves lot of advantages to verify any Editor specific bugs by cross checking on command line.

Note: On MiKTeX , I have no idea, anyone who can contribute are welcome to do so.

Comment: also `pdflatex ltxcheck`