# Installing Pythontex under windows

Tags: python

I have a newbie question.
I want to install [PythonTex](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex). I am using TeXlive 2011 on windows OS. I do not know how to proceed. 
I read the PDF file in the directory, and searched the web for a straightforward installation guide but still I do not know what to do.

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Thanks guys.

Comment: There's an installation script that is part of the package; it should work.  There are also details for manual installation in the main documentation.  TeX Live 2013 can install `pythontex` with the package manager (it's part of the full install), so you might upgrade your TeX installation if that is an option.

Comment: After installing texlive2013, I still cannot install pythontex. Maybe I try more.

Comment: Could you try some `tlmgr` and installation verification commandline checks mentiond here [tlmgr: TeX Live package manager](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145667/15717) to ensure everything is ok

Comment: @G.Poore May you add an answer with an outline of the installation procedure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by the first comment ...