# Where can I find the article.cls class file of texlive-2016 on my pc?

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I want to study the source code of `article.cls` so I can create macros of my own. If anybody can tell me the location of `article.cls` document class file, that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: if your tex system is based on tex live, it should be located in `TEXMF/tex/latex/base/article.cls`, where `TEXMF` is the root directory of the tex live "library".

Comment: try on Command line window `kpsewhich article.cls`, it would give the file path. Possible Duplicate of [What is the quickest way to check whether I already have a given package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1830/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast Although the solution is the same, I think this really is a different question.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes I am not closing the question. Upvoted your comment, I agree. I tried to search a best closely linked question even before answering.

Comment: The answer here will take you to the file, but for the code with comments you want `classes.dtx` or perhaps the full typeset `source2e.pdf` (`texdoc source2e`).

Comment: kpsewhich but simpler is just look at the terminal output any time you latex any document that uses `article` class tex always shows the full path to the class every time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way to find any file in the TeX Distribution (if you know its name) is to use the `kpsewhich` program.

From the command line type:

```
kpsewhich article.cls
```

and it should return:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

on a TeX Live system.

Depending on your OS, you may be able to open the file directly. On a Mac, e.g. I can type

```
open `kpsewhich article.cls`
```

and the file will open in my normal TeX editor.  (The back ticks pass the output of the command within the back ticks to the `open` command.)  The equivalent Linux command is `xdg-open` I believe. I have no idea if an equivalent command exists in Windows.

Comment: You could also do `vi \`kpsewhich article.cls\`` to open it with a great editor. It doesn't really matter with which program you want to open it.

Comment: @Johannes_B !wxqwqqqsw Oh I give up.

Answer (score 0):

I have idea where all document class files reside in  windows os,
if your operating system windows, MikTex Compiler then check here,

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base
```

Here, you can view all base document classes like

> `article.cls,article.sty,report.cls,report.sty,letter.cls,letter.sty`

Source code will be inside `article.cls`. `article.sty` is the latest file format `.cls` file is loaded actually inside `.sty` file.